# Ruby Dir.chdir not working in loop using unc paths

Tags: ruby

I'm trying list all files\directories from a users home directory from a list of  UNC paths (\servername\HOME\username) in a text file. I'm running Ruby in Windows. I've been using Dir.chdir to change UNC paths which has worked in a variable, but not when I use it with a list in a loop. I think I might have something wrong with my syntax?

First my text file looks something like this:

```
\\\\servername\\HOME\\username1
\\\\servername\\HOME\\username2
\\\\servername\\HOME\\username3
```

This is the program that works:

```
require 'FileUtils'

workingpath = "\\\\servername\\HOME\\username"
filename = '**/*.*'

Dir.chdir workingpath
puts Dir[filename]
```

This doesn't:

```
require 'FileUtils'

hostlist = "C:\\home_dirs.txt"
filename = '**/*.*'

File.open(hostlist).each_line do |item|  
Dir.chdir item
puts Dir[filename]
end
```

The error I keep getting is programname.rb:8:in `open': No such file or directory @ dir_initialize - \\servername\HOME\username (Errno::ENOENT).

Basically the problem is the directory never changes to the unc path. I can't figure out why since it changes directory fine in the first program. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Taking out the escape backslashes was only part of the problem. After that, the real error appears:

> Errno::EINVAL all pointing to whitespace.

I figured out that it had to be the windows newline hidden characters. I found and used .chomp and that did it! All I did was add it to item like so.

```
Dir.chdir item.chomp
```

Comment: I have edited the answer to remove the "thank you" and chatting, so that, the actual answer is more clearly visible. StackOverflow is not a discussion forum. I have also improved the text, please review it. You can edit your answer with the **edit** link below your answer. You can even rollback my edit, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to escape backslashes in your text file, because it is just data, not string literals in code. I would say that is the problem, except strangely your error message has the right number of backslashes, so something doesn't add up.

Comment: Thanks for the input! Sadly, I did try that already and tried it again to make sure. The error was slightly different:  
   
    `chdir': Invalid argument @ dir_chdir - \\servername\HOME\username1 (Errno::EINVAL)